# What's an HTML code to change the width of an eBay page?

Tags: html, ebay-design-templates

This is the what the codes I already have looks like, but I want to set it to an exact width so everything looks neat:
[image]

I'm not very good with HTML and was hoping someone could tell me what to put where. Here's the code I have:

```html
<p align="center">
  <span style="color:#000080;"><span style="font-size:48px;"><span style="font-family:times new roman,times,serif;">Product Information</span></span>
  </span>
</p>
<div>
  <h2>
    <span style="color:#000080;"><big><u><span style="background-color:#66ccff;">Description &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span></u>
    </big>
    </span>
  </h2>
</div>
<ul>
  <li>
    <span style="font-size:18px;">This is a 2016 Peyton Manning #18 Jersey.</span></li>
  <li>
    <span style="font-size:18px;">Team: Denver Broncos</span></li>
  <li>
    <span style="font-size:18px;">Player: Peyton Manning</span></li>
  <li>
    <span style="font-size:18px;">Color: Orange</span></li>
  <li>
    <span style="font-size:18px;">Brand: Nike</span></li>
  <li>
    <span style="font-size:18px;">This is a used item that has <u>NO</u> defects. No rips, tears, or stains.</span></li>
</ul>
<div>
  <div>
    <h2>
      <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 128);"><big><u><span style="background-color: rgb(102, 204, 255);">Size &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;</span></u>
      </big>
      </span>
    </h2>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      This is a Large/44 Jersey. These are the measurements:</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<p align="center">
  <img height="230" src="file:///C:/Users/JONATH~1.TOW/AppData/Local/Temp/msohtmlclip1/01/clip_image001.jpg" width="219"><img height="225" src="file:///C:/Users/JONATH~1.TOW/AppData/Local/Temp/msohtmlclip1/01/clip_image002.jpg" width="225"></p>
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:276px;" width="276">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" nowrap="nowrap" style="width:276px;height:20px;">
        <p align="center">
          Measurement Chart</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td nowrap="nowrap" style="width:63px;height:20px;">
        <p>
          <strong>Country</strong></p>
      </td>
      <td nowrap="nowrap" style="width:75px;height:20px;">
        <p>
          Length</p>
      </td>
      <td nowrap="nowrap" style="width:66px;height:20px;">
        <p>
          Width</p>
      </td>
      <td nowrap="nowrap" style="width:72px;height:20px;">
        <p>
          Sleeves</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td nowrap="nowrap" style="width:63px;height:20px;">
        <p>
          <strong>U.S.</strong></p>
      </td>
      <td nowrap="nowrap" style="width:75px;height:20px;">
        <p>
          &nbsp;</p>
      </td>
      <td nowrap="nowrap" style="width:66px;height:20px;">
        <p>
          &nbsp;</p>
      </td>
      <td nowrap="nowrap" style="width:72px;height:20px;">
        <p>
          &nbsp;</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td nowrap="nowrap" style="width:63px;height:20px;">
        <p>
          <strong>Europe</strong></p>
      </td>
      <td nowrap="nowrap" style="width:75px;height:20px;">
        <p>
          &nbsp;</p>
      </td>
      <td nowrap="nowrap" style="width:66px;height:20px;">
        <p>
          &nbsp;</p>
      </td>
      <td nowrap="nowrap" style="width:72px;height:20px;">
        <p>
          &nbsp;</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div style="clear:both;">
  &nbsp;</div>
<p>
  &nbsp;</p>
<p align="center">
  <span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size:18px;">If you want further details on the sizing, please feel free to message us!</span></span>
</p>
<div>
  <div>
    <h2>
      <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 128);"><big><u><span style="background-color: rgb(102, 204, 255);">Shipping &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;</span></u>
      </big>
      </span>
    </h2>
  </div>
  <ul>
  </ul>
  <p>
    <span style="font-size:18px;">This item is shipped using USPS Priority Mail. It is shipped out of St. Paul, MN 55014.</span></p>
</div>
<div>
  <br>
  <span style="font-size:18px;">We try to ship this package within 24 hour of the time you pay for the item.<br>
We ship Internationally.</span></div>
<p>
  <span style="font-size:18px;"><img src="http://thebuttonpost.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/priority-mail.png" style="margin-left: 12px; margin-right: 12px; float: right; width: 220px; height: 131px;"></span></p>
<div>
  &nbsp;</div>
<p>
  <span style="font-size:18px;"><u>The following is included in this shipment:</u></span></p>
<div>
  <p>
    <span style="font-size:18px;">1.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 2-4 Day Shipping in the US</span></p>
  <div>
    <p>
      <span style="font-size:18px;">2.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Free Tracking</span></p>
    <p>
      <span style="font-size:18px;">3.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Insurance for your package up to $50.00</span></p>
    <div>
      &nbsp;</div>
    <p>
      <span style="font-size:18px;">Please insure that your address is correct. If you are worried your package could be stolen please contact your Post Office with the tracking number and have them hold it there for you. Unfortunately once the tracking shows the package has been delivered to the address it is your responsibility and refunds cannot be accepted.</span></p>
    <p>
      <span style="font-size:18px;">If your package was damaged by USPS, please contact us ASAP with photos showing the extent of the damage. You will be refunded and we will take care of making an insurance claim with USPS since packaging was our responsibility.</span></p>
    <p>
      &nbsp;</p>
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2>
          <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 128);"><big><u><span style="background-color: rgb(102, 204, 255);">Return Policy &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</span></u>
          </big>
          </span>
        </h2>
      </div>
      <p>
        <span style="font-size:18px;">We try to make the description of the item you’re buying as detailed as possible to avoid the need for returns. If your item contains a defect that was not listed in the description we will accept a return with photos of the defect. If the item’s defect is clearly not in the photos we posted, or seem to be manufactured, your return will not be accepted.</span></p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2>
          <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 128);"><big><u><span style="background-color: rgb(102, 204, 255);">Payment &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</span></u>
          </big>
          </span>
        </h2>
      </div>
      <p>
        <span style="font-size:18px;">We accept PayPal and Credit/Debit cards. After you click “Purchase Item” you are not done checking out! Click on <u>PAY NOW</u>. Your package will not be shipped until you pay for your item, and it will be cancelled if you do not pay within 2 Business Days.</span></p>
    </div>
    <p align="center">
      &nbsp;</p>
    <p align="center">
      &nbsp;</p>
    <p style="text-align: center;">
      <img alt="" src="http://www.bceldercare.ca/images/paypal-verified.png" style="width: 500px; height: 146px;"></p>
    <p align="center">
      &nbsp;</p>
  </div>
</div>
<p>
  &nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: Try changing the `font-sizes`

Comment: @LancePreston I don't think thats what he asked for

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend a fixed width.  On mobile devices your template wont show very well.  I would recommend you look a simple responsive grid css layout like skeleton - it will resize it all to the width of the browser, works fine in eBay!

Comment: As long-time buyer and seller using multiple devices, I feel compelled to back up James on this. While a fixed width will give you a rigid boundary within which you can compose your listing, you run the risk of annoying potential buyers using smaller displays who can't be bothered to scroll back-and-forth in order to read all the content. This can be particularly hazardous to the seller if key details or description elements are offscreen beyond the right side of the page, and the customer doesn't read it (or isn't aware that there is anything over there) before bidding or buying.

Answer (score 0):

How about putting your entire page in a container, giving that container a width of how big you want it to be and centering it. In my snippet, I gave the container a width of 50vw (Which equals to 50% of the current viewport width)

```css
#container{
  width:50vw;
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<p align="center">
<span style="color:#000080;"><span style="font-size:48px;"><span style="font-family:times new roman,times,serif;">Product Information</span></span></span></p>
<div>
<h2>
<span style="color:#000080;"><big><u><span style="background-color:#66ccff;">Description &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span></u></big></span></h2>
</div>
<ul>
<li>
<span style="font-size:18px;">This is a 2016 Peyton Manning #18 Jersey.</span></li>
<li>
<span style="font-size:18px;">Team: Denver Broncos</span></li>
<li>
<span style="font-size:18px;">Player: Peyton Manning</span></li>
<li>
<span style="font-size:18px;">Color: Orange</span></li>
<li>
<span style="font-size:18px;">Brand: Nike</span></li>
<li>
<span style="font-size:18px;">This is a used item that has <u>NO</u> defects. No rips, tears, or stains.</span></li>
</ul>
<div>
<div>
<h2>
<span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 128);"><big><u><span style="background-color: rgb(102, 204, 255);">Size &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;</span></u></big></span></h2>
</div>
<ul>
<li>
This is a Large/44 Jersey. These are the measurements:</li>
</ul>
</div>
<p align="center">
<img height="230" src="file:///C:/Users/JONATH~1.TOW/AppData/Local/Temp/msohtmlclip1/01/clip_image001.jpg" width="219"><img height="225" src="file:///C:/Users/JONATH~1.TOW/AppData/Local/Temp/msohtmlclip1/01/clip_image002.jpg" width="225"></p>
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:276px;" width="276">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="4" nowrap="nowrap" style="width:276px;height:20px;">
<p align="center">
Measurement Chart</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td nowrap="nowrap" style="width:63px;height:20px;">
<p>
<strong>Country</strong></p>
</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" style="width:75px;height:20px;">
<p>
Length</p>
</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" style="width:66px;height:20px;">
<p>
Width</p>
</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" style="width:72px;height:20px;">
<p>
Sleeves</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td nowrap="nowrap" style="width:63px;height:20px;">
<p>
<strong>U.S.</strong></p>
</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" style="width:75px;height:20px;">
<p>
&nbsp;</p>
</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" style="width:66px;height:20px;">
<p>
&nbsp;</p>
</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" style="width:72px;height:20px;">
<p>
&nbsp;</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td nowrap="nowrap" style="width:63px;height:20px;">
<p>
<strong>Europe</strong></p>
</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" style="width:75px;height:20px;">
<p>
&nbsp;</p>
</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" style="width:66px;height:20px;">
<p>
&nbsp;</p>
</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" style="width:72px;height:20px;">
<p>
&nbsp;</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div style="clear:both;">
&nbsp;</div>
<p>
&nbsp;</p>
<p align="center">
<span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size:18px;">If you want further details on the sizing, please feel free to message us!</span></span></p>
<div>
<div>
<h2>
<span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 128);"><big><u><span style="background-color: rgb(102, 204, 255);">Shipping &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;</span></u></big></span></h2>
</div>
<ul>
</ul>
<p>
<span style="font-size:18px;">This item is shipped using USPS Priority Mail. It is shipped out of St. Paul, MN 55014.</span></p>
</div>
<div>
<br>
<span style="font-size:18px;">We try to ship this package within 24 hour of the time you pay for the item.<br>
We ship Internationally.</span></div>
<p>
<span style="font-size:18px;"><img src="http://thebuttonpost.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/priority-mail.png" style="margin-left: 12px; margin-right: 12px; float: right; width: 220px; height: 131px;"></span></p>
<div>
&nbsp;</div>
<p>
<span style="font-size:18px;"><u>The following is included in this shipment:</u></span></p>
<div>
<p>
<span style="font-size:18px;">1.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 2-4 Day Shipping in the US</span></p>
<div>
<p>
<span style="font-size:18px;">2.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Free Tracking</span></p>
<p>
<span style="font-size:18px;">3.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Insurance for your package up to $50.00</span></p>
<div>
&nbsp;</div>
<p>
<span style="font-size:18px;">Please insure that your address is correct. If you are worried your package could be stolen please contact your Post Office with the tracking number and have them hold it there for you. Unfortunately once the tracking shows the package has been delivered to the address it is your responsibility and refunds cannot be accepted.</span></p>
<p>
<span style="font-size:18px;">If your package was damaged by USPS, please contact us ASAP with photos showing the extent of the damage. You will be refunded and we will take care of making an insurance claim with USPS since packaging was our responsibility.</span></p>
<p>
&nbsp;</p>
<div>
<div>
<h2>
<span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 128);"><big><u><span style="background-color: rgb(102, 204, 255);">Return Policy &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</span></u></big></span></h2>
</div>
<p>
<span style="font-size:18px;">We try to make the description of the item you’re buying as detailed as possible to avoid the need for returns. If your item contains a defect that was not listed in the description we will accept a return with photos of the defect. If the item’s defect is clearly not in the photos we posted, or seem to be manufactured, your return will not be accepted.</span></p>
</div>
<div>
<div>
<h2>
<span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 128);"><big><u><span style="background-color: rgb(102, 204, 255);">Payment &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</span></u></big></span></h2>
</div>
<p>
<span style="font-size:18px;">We accept PayPal and Credit/Debit cards. After you click “Purchase Item” you are not done checking out! Click on <u>PAY NOW</u>. Your package will not be shipped until you pay for your item, and it will be cancelled if you do not pay within 2 Business Days.</span></p>
</div>
<p align="center">
&nbsp;</p>
<p align="center">
&nbsp;</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">
<img alt="" src="http://www.bceldercare.ca/images/paypal-verified.png" style="width: 500px; height: 146px;"></p>
<p align="center">
&nbsp;</p>
</div>
</div>
<p>
&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```